# In PHP, is it a problem to call a static class function using the -> dereferencer

Tags: php, oop, class, static-methods, dereference

I am using PHP 5.2

I have the following code:

```
class MyClass {
    public function __construct() {}

    public static function stuff() {
        echo 'This is static! <br />';
    }

}

$myClass = new MyClass();

MyClass::stuff(); // Reference by class.

$myClass->stuff(); // Reference by instance of class.
```

The output works in both cases here is the output:

**This is static!**

**This is static!**

Is there a problem using the 2nd way of referencing versus the 1st?

Since I am not allowed to have a non-static function with the same signature as the static one above that won't be an issue. I want the function to be static because there is also a speed boost when using static functions.

Am I missing anything or is the only issue here regarding the semantics of how the -> dereference syntax does not indicate this is a static function?

Comment: It's functionally equivalent. The static call will just run with an empty local scope, whereas `->` calls will have a $this instance. The "static" keyword is mostly a NOP for your case, relevant for self:: references only.

Comment: @mario, that's incorrect.  Either way, it's a static method and `$this` is not available.

Answer (score 6):

The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) explicitly say it's okay:

> A property declared as static can not
>   be accessed with an instantiated class
>   object (though a static method can).

However, it's clearer to use `::`.  I also question the idea that the static method is significantly faster, particularly when no instance fields are used.  You should do profiling before you start altering the semantics of your application for performance.